# How to send a curl request with pem certificate via PHP?

Tags: php, apache, api, ssl, curl

I have a php script in my Apache server that have to send a curl request to a partner's server.
Partner give me a .pem file that I have to attach to every call I do to its api.

My php script is the follow:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "test.pem" );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,"PEM");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$result)
{
    echo "Curl Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo "Success: ". $result;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

It returns:

> Curl Error: unable to set private key file: 'test.pem' type PEM

Consider that it sends me .pem file and says "it has no passphrase"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that you need to use the [tmpfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) and [stream_get_meta_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php).

```
$pemFile = tmpfile();
fwrite($pemFile, "test.pem");//the path for the pem file
$tempPemPath = stream_get_meta_data($pemFile);
$tempPemPath = $tempPemPath['uri'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $tempPemPath);
```

Source: [This answer here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038338/3943162) helps me with similar problem.

Comment: Hi James, thanks very much!!! I implemented the code and now it report: "Curl Error: could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)" Do you know what it means?

Comment: The problem could be your pem file. Are you on a windows environment ? See if this [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste) helps you. Ensure that your file starts with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`, with no spaces.

Comment: Thanks very much James!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  'test.pem');`
Have a look at [cURL is unable to use client certificate , in local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470225/curl-is-unable-to-use-client-certificate-in-local-server)
for more about using client certificates in curl via PHP