# Equivalent of a CURL command with certificates in PHP

Tags: php, curl, certificate

I'm need to know how to write the follow CURL command in PHP, I tried it from various modes and I searched in many articles here in the StackOverflow and I tried to adaptate the code but nothing is really working:

```
curl -v --insecure --cert public-certified-with-chain.pem --key private-key.key -nodes GET "MY_URL" "accept: */*"
```

I managed to reach this stage, but it doesn't work:

```
   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://...');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   echo $result;
```

The code above is simplified, it return a result, but still showing "Unauthorized".

How to adapt it to attach the files?

Comment: Show us your best try, it helps us write a more targetted answer

Comment: Done! I edited the question with my code

Comment: And what is the problem with that code?

Comment: I don't know. When I send it to server is returned 'Unauthorized'. But when I use the CURL as command line it work well.

Comment: Check the error using ['curl_error()`](https://www.php.net/curl_%20error) and then show us the error

Comment: I edited the question. Apparently this action should be simple. 

In this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958892/passing-pem-and-key-as-string-in-curl-using-php

A answer recomends to use 'stream_get_meta_data', maybe be it?

Comment: I could post a more versatile function that would give access to more verbose information about the request which is often really useful in debugging requests with curl that fail. It might help

Answer (score 1):

curl's `--cert` option corresponds to `CURLOPT_SSLCERT`, which isn't present in your PHP code.

I suggest you add `--libcurl sample.c` to your command line to get a code template (in C), that you then can translate to PHP.

Also, the command line shown in the question doesn't appear to be a fully working curl command line.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, I'll check it.